# Retain formatting when exporting datagridview to excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I have a working code which imports Excel data to a datagridview and applies background color based on different limit values for each column. I want to retain the background color when I export this to Excel, but I cannot find out how to implement this in my code.

First an example of how I apply background color to the datagridview:

```
        Dim Ul1Zn As Double = 200
    Dim Ul2Zn As Double = 500
    Dim Ul3Zn As Double = 1000
    Dim Ul4Zn As Double = 5000
    Dim Ul5Zn As Double = 25000

    For i As Double = 0 To Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value < Ul1Zn Then
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Style.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
        ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value >= Ul1Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value < Ul2Zn Then
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
        ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value >= Ul2Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value < Ul3Zn Then
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value >= Ul3Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value < Ul4Zn Then
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
        ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value >= Ul4Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value < Ul5Zn Then
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Value >= Ul5Zn Then
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Zn (Sink)").Style.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        End If
    Next
```

(Edited) And this is my export code:

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    ' Creating a Excel object.
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

    Try

        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

        worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid"

        Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1


        'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = DataGridView2.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next


        'As
        Dim UL1As As Double = 8
        Dim UL2As As Double = 20
        Dim UL3As As Double = 50
        Dim Ul4As As Double = 600
        Dim Ul5As As Double = 1000

        'Gir ikke feilmelding, men lager heller ikke farge


        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1
                If Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL1As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL1As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL2As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL2As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL3As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL3As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < Ul4As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= Ul4As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < Ul5As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= Ul5As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
        Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        excel.Quit()
        workbook = Nothing
        excel = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

Progress! I removed the argument about "if column name is As (Arsen)..." Now the entire row gets colored, however, and I only want the individual cells under the relevant column to be affected. My original column specifying argument did not work, apparently. Anyone guess what was wrong with it?

Previous code. Did not color background, but did not crash:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1
                If Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "As (Arsen)" And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL1As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "As (Arsen)" And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL1As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL2As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "As (Arsen)" And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL2As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL3As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "As (Arsen)" And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL3As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < Ul4As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "As (Arsen)" And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= Ul4As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < Ul5As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "As (Arsen)" And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= Ul5As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you are going to have to do this during the export. While looping through the `DataGridView` cells you will have to check the values and change the `Excel` cells interior color if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the input; that sounds like a way forward. Any Idea what that code would look like for my example? ;)

Comment: Do this the same way you are formatting the `DataGridView` cells if the value is within a range. Currently your export code above is looping through the `DataGridView` rows then each column. Example: As it loops through the columns apply a check `if (cellColumnIndex.name == “Zn (Sink)”)` then check its value and if it is less than 200 then color the Excel cell blue. As I said earlier this is the same thing you are doing in the `DataGridView`, simply apply the same logic when exporting.

Comment: Changing an `Excel`s range interior color would be something like: `range1.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);` depending on what Excel library you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnG, I'll give it a go :)

Comment: If I'm exporting using Interop, what would the coloring code be?

Comment: The code to set the interior color is posted in my last comment. It was taken from a working export to excel using interop.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: NP glad you got it working.

Comment: `worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color =`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Slai. I couldn't get it to work, though.

Comment: After a couple of days of problem solving, your suggestion turned out to work great, @Slai. Thanks :)